# How to display string with forward slash and hyphen in a textbox?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to generate a report in SSRS 2012, but the textbox does not display the following kind of string returned from datasource:

> UUU/GDS/CGD/09-10/00227

I have a feeling there is a way to make such a string display. I think it is possible to escape the special characters, but since this is not a static field maybe I need some expression that ensures that any string with any order of such characters can display in the textbox.

Does anyone know how?

Here is the expression for the textbox value:

```
=Fields!ControlDeskInterface_1_purchaseOrderLine_1_purchaseOrderHeader_miscellaneousReference1.Value
```

Comment: What specific issue are you getting? I tested against a simple report based on a dataset from `select 'UUU/GDS/CGD/09-10/00227' as val` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is more going for your issue - I can display the above string with no issues:

Dataset:

[image]

Simple report to display Dataset:

[image]

End result:

[image]

SSRS is just accepting the string and displaying it without any changes. Do you have any formatting on the TextBox where it's displayed or anything like that?